# How to get the error message when PyRun_AnyFile failed

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to embed python in my c++ project by using `PyRun_AnyFile`.

Here is my python script:

```
import aaa

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Here")
```

Here is my c++ code:

```
const char pFile[] = "C:\\testing.py";
FILE* fp = _Py_fopen(pFile, "r");
int ret = PyRun_AnyFile(fp, pFile);
```

I get error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import aaa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aaa'
```

This is expected. **I would like to ask how I get the above error message in the code and redirect it to other error files.**

I have tried:

```
PyObject* ptype, * pvalue, * ptraceback;
PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
Py_ssize_t string_len = 0;
std::wcout << std::wstring(PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(pvalue, &string_len)) << std::endl;
```

or:

```
PyErr_Print();
```

But that is not success.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem some time ago. I solved reading of error that way. You have to execute this code after recognizing that there was an error on script execution.

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import traceback, sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("trace = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback))");
PyObject *mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
if (PyObject_HasAttrString(mainModule, std::string("trace").c_str())) {
    PyObject *var = PyObject_GetAttrString(mainModule, std::string("trace").c_str());
    if (PyUnicode_Check(var)) {
        std::string errMsg = (std::string) PyUnicode_AsUTF8(var) + "\n";
        std::cout << errMsg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried but this is not working for me. I then redirect the path in the script `sys.stderr = open(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), os.path.basename(__file__) + "_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + "_stderr" + ".log"), "w")`